# what does this string mean such as "ED845558-5168-45C0-BA98-43AB3C238E9F"?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

In the iphonesimulator5.1, I found that the directory is like this:

..../5.1/Appliciton/ED845558-5168-45C0-BA98-43AB3C238E9F/*.app

My question is, what does the string mean? why we need  a named directory like this ? and what this number imply for?

Comment: This is a wild guess, but could it be the GUID?

Comment: Seems like an unique identifier... generally they are used to avoid collisions... more info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a unique ID, randomly generated, to make sure that one app's files don't mix with any other's.

Comment: I just want to know how does it informed. Has it some rules for create it?

Comment: It is random. The Wikipedia article on [GUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) explains how they are formed.